# trying to get device registrationid using cordova is this code correct?

Tags: cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to get the device registration id gcm i have used the cordova push plugin https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin however i am not getting the id in alert?..I am wondering what is gone wrong.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var pushNotification;
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>deviceready event received</li>');

            /*document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e)
            {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>backbutton event received</li>');

                if( $("#home").length > 0)
                {
                    // call this to get a new token each time. don't call it to reuse existing token.
                    //pushNotification.unregister(successHandler, errorHandler);
                    e.preventDefault();
                    navigator.app.exitApp();
                }
                else
                {
                    navigator.app.backHistory();
                }
            }, false);
        */
            try 
            {
                alert('try block');
                pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
          $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering ' + device.platform + '</li>');

                if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' ||
                        device.platform == 'amazon-fireos' ) {
                    alert('try block2');
        pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {"senderID":"Mysenderid","ecb":"onNotification"});      // required!
                } else {
                    pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"});    // required!
                }
            }
            catch(err) 
            { 
                txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n"; 
                txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n"; 
                alert(txt); 
            } 
        }

        // handle APNS notifications for iOS
        function onNotificationAPN(e) {
            if (e.alert) {
                 $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>push-notification: ' + e.alert + '</li>');
                 // showing an alert also requires the org.apache.cordova.dialogs plugin
                 navigator.notification.alert(e.alert);
            }

            if (e.sound) {
                // playing a sound also requires the org.apache.cordova.media plugin
                var snd = new Media(e.sound);
                snd.play();
            }

            if (e.badge) {
                pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, e.badge);
            }
        }

        // handle GCM notifications for Android
        function onNotification(e) {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');

            switch( e.event )
            {
                case 'registered':
                if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
                {
                    alert('case registered');
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
                    // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
                    // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
                    alert("regID = " + e.regid);
                }
                break;

                case 'message':
                    // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
                    // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
                    if (e.foreground)
                    {
                        alert('message');
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--INLINE NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');

                            // on Android soundname is outside the payload. 
                                // On Amazon FireOS all custom attributes are contained within payload
                                var soundfile = e.soundname || e.payload.sound;
                                // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
                                // playing a sound also requires the org.apache.cordova.media plugin
                                var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/"+ soundfile);

                        my_media.play();
                    }
                    else
                    {   // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
                        alert('else');
                        if (e.coldstart)
                            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                        else
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                    }

                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');
                    //android only
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + '</li>');
                    //amazon-fireos only
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> TIMESTAMP: ' + e.payload.timeStamp + '</li>');
                break;

                case 'error':
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
                break;

                default:
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is</li>');
                break;
            }
        }

        function tokenHandler (result) {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>token: '+ result +'</li>');
            // Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
            // here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
        }

        function successHandler (result) {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>success:'+ result +'</li>');
        }

        function errorHandler (error) {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>error:'+ error +'</li>');
        }

        document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);

     </script>
```

Comment: have you installed `device` plugin ?

Comment: this piece of code `if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' ` requires device plugin.

Comment: Hi I have installed the plugin using the manual install .. if I do the automatic install that is cordova add plugin PushPlugin then my application fails to buid.

Comment: you also need to install this plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device , this code is also using `device plugin`.

Comment: I have checked by trying cordova plugin list but I am not able to see the pushplugin

Comment: The version you are using is deprecated, try using [https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push), see if you'll have the same issue. Also a test app to guide you through: [https://github.com/hollyschinsky/PushNotificationSample](https://github.com/hollyschinsky/PushNotificationSample)